# What is the difference between using display: flow-root and overflow: hidden to contain floats?

Tags: css, display

A new [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=control) value `flow-root` has been added to the [css](/questions/tagged/css) spec:

> The element generates a block container box, and lays out its contents using flow layout. It always establishes a new block formatting context for its contents. [CSS2] – https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-flow-root

There are [many ways to create a block context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), e.g. `overflow: hidden`.

What is different about using `display: flow-root` vs `overflow: hidden` to contain float-ed elements?

Answer (score 12):

`display: flow-root` allows your flow root element to have `overflow: visible` if that's important to you, since block boxes with `overflow: visible` do not normally establish block formatting contexts.

Comment: I was primarily not clear about when one would seek to float elements without wanting to clip overflow-ing content. After talking on IRC about it, one possible use case is to enable tooltips for floated elements.